# Storing large objects in Couchbase - best practice?

Tags: blob, couchbase

In my system, a user can upload very large files, which I need to store in Couchbase. I don't need such very large objects to persist in memory, but I want them to be always read/written from/to disk. These files are read-only (never modified). The user can upload them, delete them, download them, but never update them. For some technical constraints, my system cannot store those files in the file system, so they have to be stored into the database.

I've done some research and found an article[1] saying that storing large objects in a database is generally a bad idea, especially with Couchbase, but at the same time provides some advice: create a secondary bucket with a low RAM quota, tune up the value/full eviction policy. My concern is the limit of 20Mb mentioned by the author. My files would be much larger than that.

What's the best approach to follow to store large files into Couchbase without having them persist in memory? Is it possible to raise the limit of 20Mb in case? Shall I create a secondary bucket with a very low RAM quota and a full eviction policy?

[1]http://blog.couchbase.com/2016/january/large-objects-in-a-database

Comment: It is not that storing objects is a bad idea "especially in Couchbase". It is not unique to Couchbase.

Comment: I got that, although I have always stored large binary objects in RDBMs (Oracle, MS SQL Server, Postgres, MySQL) with no particular problems. When it comes to storing the same information in Couchbase, as said, I am a bit concerned by the fact that such amount of data would persist in memory. Is there a best practice to stick to in case one wants to store large objects in Couchbase anyway?

Comment: Then the two bucket scenario above is probably the best option.

For storing objects larger than 20MB, you will have to do the splitting yourself into multiple objects.

For larger RDBMS databases, I have had problems with them at scale. I managed a 15TB Oracle database and the reason it was that large was because all of the binary data. The service ended up costing over $1 million a year because of the storage and size of hardware needed. That cost was a factor of that service's ultimate demise.

Comment: Thanks! Do you think that full eviction and high-priority disk I/O would be good options for that bucket? I was thinking that full eviction would prevent those data to stay in memory, while a high-priority disk I/O would force them to be written to disk asap. Am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, Couchbase engineers recommend that you not store large files in Couchbase. Instead, you can store the files on some file server (like AWS or Azure Blob or something) and instead store the meta-data about the files in Couchbase.

Comment: As said in my post, I can't use an external storage service.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [couchbase blog posting](http://blog.couchbase.com/2016/january/storing-blobs-in-couchbase-for-content-management) that gives a pretty detailed breakdown of how to do what you want to do in Couchbase.

This is Java API specific but the general approach can work with any of the Couchbase SDKs, I'm actually in the midst of doing something pretty similar right now with the node SDK.

I can't speak for what couchbase engineers recommend but they've posted this blog entry detailing how to do it.

For large files, you'll certainly want to split into chunks.  Do not attempt to store a big file all in one document.  The approach I'm looking at is to chunk the data, and insert it under the file sha1 hash.   So file "Foo.docx" would get split into say 4 chunks, which would be "sha1|0", "sha1|1" and so on, where sha1 is the hash of the document.  This would also enable a setup where you can store the same file under many different names.

Tradeoffs -- if integration with Amazon S3 is an option for you, you might be better off with that.  In general chunking data in a DB like what I describe is going to be more complicated to implement, and much slower, than using something like Amazon S3.  But that has to be traded off other requirements, like whether or not you can keep sensitive files in S3, or whether you want to deal with maintaining a filesystem and the associated scaling of that.

So it depends on what your requirements are.  If you want speed/performance, don't put your files in Couchbase -- but can you do it?  Sure.   I've done it myself, and the blog post above describes a separate way to do it.

There are all kinds of interesting extensions you might wish to implement, depending on your needs.  For example, if you commonly store many different files with similar content, you might implement a blocking strategy that would allow single-store of many common segments, to save space.  Other solutions like S3 will happily store copies of copies of copies of copies, and gleefully charge you huge amounts of money to do so.

**EDIT** as a follow-up, there's [this other Couchbase post](http://blog.couchbase.com/2016/january/large-objects-in-a-database) talking about why storing in the DB might not be a good idea.  Reasonable things to consider - but again it depends on your application-specific requirements.  "Use S3" I think would be generally good advice, but won't work for everyone.

Comment: Thanks. I've read both posts (one I had already linked in my original question) but they don't help much. Yes, I will consider chunking the blob. I am more interested in knowing, however, how I should create a seconday bucket, with which options: full eviction? High-priority I/O?

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB has an option to do this sort of thing, and it's supported in almost all drivers: GridFS. You could do something like GridFS in Couchbase, which is to make a metadata collection (bucket) and a chunk collection with fixed size blobs. GridFS allows you to change the blob size per file,  but all blobs must be the same size. The filesize is stored in the metadata. A typical chunk size is 2048, and are restricted to powers of 2.

You don't need memory cache for files, you can queue up the chunks for download in your app server. You may want to try GridFS on Mongo first, and then see if you can adapt it to Couchbase, but there is always this: https://github.com/couchbaselabs/cbfs

Answer (score 0):

This is the best practice: do not take couchbase database as the main database consider it as sync database because no matter how you chunk data into small pieces it will go above 20MB size which will hit you in long run, so having a strong database like MySQL in a middle will help to save those large data then use couchbase for realtime and sync only.